# Can we reset chrome extension's trial version in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-extension

I am using selenium and have loaded an extension 'NopeCha' (which solves ReCaptchas) in my driver. But the extension in its trial version only gives 100 solves in free trial.
I was wondering if there was a trick to reset it, so I can use the 100 solves again!

My Code:

```
#for randomizing user agent
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
print(userAgent)
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
chrome_options.add_extension('NopeCHA-CAPTCHA-Solver.crx')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
keyword = "doctor"
site = "linkedin.com"
driver.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?q=%2B92+contact+email+{keyword}+site%3A{site}")
```

But everytime chome starts, the Extension's solve count is still there where I left it...

Any help will be HUGELY appreciated!

What I tried:
-Changing the user agent
-Changing the chromedriver.exe file
-Deleting the extensions folder in C:\users(user)\appdata...\extensions
-And adding countless arguments to chrome_options.

and it didn't affected the browser a single bit!

Comment: Have you considered, I don't know, getting the full version? What you're trying to do is kinda unethical, if not straight up illegal.

Comment: Do you understand the possibility that your question is seen by the NopeCha developers?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried your browser simulation with TOR browser, maybe it will grant your wish.